# Configuration for action cable for postgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

How will the configuration file, `config/cable.yml` look like for a postgreSQL adapter?

Answer (score 13):

This is working for me:

```
# config/cable.yml
production:
  adapter: postgresql

development:
  adapter: postgresql

test:
  adapter: postgresql
```

The postgresql adapter uses the pg [notify command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html). Keep in mind that the message body must be smaller than 8000 bytes.

Comment: This is because of: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#postgresql-adapter